# How do I make a child of an absolutely positioned div stick to the bottom of it's absolutely positioned parent?

Tags: html, css

The title question says it all. Essentially, I have an absolutely positioned div, and within it, I am trying to position a div that will stick to its bottom.

Using `position: fixed` does to do what I want to do. `Fixed` yields a div that is always stuck to the bottom of the screen regardless of the user scrolling through overflowing content of the parent.

Any input as to how I could go about doing this would be great.

Here's a fiddle you guys could use to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/y48kB/

Comment: Well... http://jsfiddle.net/bUjbv/

Comment: Why don't use position absolute to #stickbottom element?

Comment: answer already posted ^. This one is a way too "common sensed" answer lol

Answer (score 3):

Just add position absolute in the child : http://jsfiddle.net/bUjbv/

```
#absoluteParent{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:crimson;
    position:absolute;
}

#stickToBottom{
    position: absolute;
    background:green;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be best practice http://jsfiddle.net/y48kB/4/

```
<div id="absoluteParent">
  <div class="relativeDiv">
    <div id="stickToBottom">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#absoluteParent{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:crimson;
    position:absolute;
}
.relativeDiv {
    position: relative; width:400px; height: 400px;
}
#stickToBottom{
    background:green;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```